whereIn in firestore works differently in console and in dart
I am trying to create filters on a collection documents. Each filter corresponds to a field in doc.
when i try the query in Firebase console it allows me to have multiple 'in' clauses in Ui and it shows the results too without any error. When I try to do the same in a dart query(whereIn clause) then I get this error that 'multiple 'whereIn' are not allowed. Gemini also confirms that it's allowed and I can't find this clarification in firestore docs. please clarify.
I have data in Firstore db with these fields:
{
    Key1 = val.1, va 1.2, val1.3,
    Key2 = val2.1, val2.2, val2.3
    Key3 = val3.1, val3.2, val3.3
}

I have filters on Key1/2/3 and in the filters user will select a combination of one or more value from key1/2/3 e.g. show the results where key1=val1.2 OR 1.3 AND key2 = val2.3
I used the firebase Firestore query UI on console and creates query there like this:
{key1, in \[val1.2, val1.3\] AND key2, in \[val2.3\]}

and it showed me the results.
When I was trying to achives this via whereIn clause in Flutter/Dart i.e
query.where(Key1, whereIn:\[val1.2, val1.3\]).where(key2, whereIn:\[val2.3\])

I received an error that only one whereIn is allowed.
On the net one work around was given that for the filtering purpose put all the filtering values in one field and use whereIn on that filed so I created a field in doc like this:
filter=val.1, val1.2, val1.3, val2.1, val2.2, val2.3, val3.1, val3.2, val3.3

but problem here is that its not AND of two conditions. any single value match returns the data and its a lot of data in that case.
Another solution was to use whereIn and arrayContains on different fields but I need more such checks for other fields and arrayContainsAny also has the similar 'once only' restriction so I am kind of running out of operators and after coming so far in my app development I am kind of stuck.

Please edit your question to include: 1) a screenshot of the query (and results) in the console, 2) the Dart code (as text) and the exact error message (also as text).

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
